# Bash shell: How to assign the value of $A to $B given $B='$A' (string, dollar A)?

Tags: string, bash, shell

In Bash shell, given variable

```
$B = "$A"
```

which is the string literal and I need to check if the value of `B` starts with a dollar sign:

```
if [[ $B == *"$"* ]]; then
```

How do I assign the value of variable, whose name is the string value of $B, to $B itself?

Thanks!

Update:
To make my question clear, I'll use another example, say I have a variable

```
$SCORE = 100
```

and another variable

```
$B = '$SCORE'
```

a string variable whose value is the dollar sign name of SCORE, now I want to assign the actual integer score (100) to variable $B.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the value of `$B`? Are you asking how to check if the value of a variable is `$some_other_variable` and, if it is, how to assign the value of *that* variable (i.e. the value of `$some_other_variable`) as the value of the original variable (i.e. `$B`)?

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner I think you are right, the value of Score, say is 100, and the value of B is a string, "$Score", and I want to get the value of the variable, whose name is the value of B (in this case, $Score)

Comment: You are thinking of indirect reference. Use indirection. Say `B="Score"` and `Score=100`, then `echo ${!B}` should print 100.

Comment: If `B='$SCORE'` and `SCORE=100`, then you cannot use indirection. Just use the unsafe `eval` since you are in control of the variable, I hope.

Comment: @alvits thanks it works!

Comment: `declare` is slightly safer than `eval`, but I strongly suggest you simply change the code that sets `B='$SCORE'` to `B=SCORE` so that you *can* use indirect parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change your requirements a bit, you can use [variable "indirection"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
score=100
b="score"
echo "${!b}"   # note the bang
```

If the `$` has to be there:

```
b='$score'
tmp=${b/#$}     # remove the leading $
echo "${!tmp}"
```